# Theming Prestashop 1.5.3

Tags: prestashop, theming

Already about two weeks, I'm looking for a normal and adequate self-learning tutorial on Prestashop 1.5.3 theming. On official presta web-site i find some small presentation of the material about theming, but it very small info for it.

**Who know where can i find more detailed info about prestashop 1.5.3 theming?**

Sincerely, John!

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop is a french project, you'll find some resources in french. But in english, apart the official doc :
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Designer+Guide

The best way to begin is to duplicate the default theme and hack it. After that you well understand structure and assigned smarty variables, you'll be able to start a theme from scratch.

Comment: Good advice. You can also google free themes for Prestashop 1.5 and see how they're done.